# How to reach to a very deeply nested A HREF for my spider to find the NEXT button?

Tags: css, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am making my second spider, and I am finding this particular structure which is very complicated for me, I hope you can help me.

I have this html page (please note, all unnecesary data is removed, I only left the link that I am interested in:

```
            <html>
                <head>
                </head>

            <body>
            <form>
                <div>
                </div>
                <script>        
                </script>
                <div>
                </div>
                <script>        
                </script>
                <div>
                    <div>   
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div>

                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <div>
                                                <div>

                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <script>
                                                        </script>
                                                        <div>
                                                            <p></p>
                                                            <div></div>
                                                            <script></script>
                                                            <div></div>
                                                            <script></script>
                                                            <div></div>
                                                            <script></script>
                                                            <div></div>
                                                            <script></script>                                                                                                                           
                                                            <div></div>
                                                            <script></script>
                                                            <div></div>
                                                            <script></script>
                                                            <div></div>
                                                            <script></script>
                                                            <div></div>
                                                            <script></script>                                                                                                                           <div></div>
                                                            <script></script>                                                                                                                           
                                                            <div></div>
                                                            <script></script>
                                                            <div></div>
                                                            <script></script>
                                                            <div></div>
                                                            <script></script>
                                                            <div></div>
                                                            <script></script>
                                                            <table class="pageTable">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td></td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <span></span>
                                                                        <span></span>
                                                                        <span></span>
                                                                        <a href></a>
                                                                        <a href></a>
                                                                        <a href></a>
                                                                        <a href></a>
                                                                        <a href></a>
                                                                        <a href></a>
                                                                        <a href></a>
                                                                        <a href></a>
                                                                        <a href></a>
                                                                        <a href="whatever.com" class="wx4">next</a>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>                    
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

            </body>
            </html>
```

(this is the actual structure).

Now, specifically my need is for my spider to follow that link (inside the table, under the 3 spans and after 9 A tags). All the rest of the extraction logic is done.

Ironically, none of the tags have any class or id at all, except the table and the  I am interested in. But for some strange reason, when I try to access it using scrapy, I get the following result:

```
>>> response.css('a.wx4').extract()
[]
>>>
```

Do you have any idea what could I be doing wrong?
Is it because it's inside a < td > along with a bunch of < a >, nested inside < tr >, < table >, many < div > and one < form >?

Thanks!

Comment: That looks like it should work. It's possible that there is some broken markup which is not being parsed correctly, but it's hard to tell for sure without seeing the actual website.

Comment: Your code seems good to me, to add something to @stranac comment, maybe the css class is added with javascript and is not present on the original HTML code that is what scrapy parse. To check that, inspect the html code in your browser with javascript disabled.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath will find the last anchor element:

```
response.selector.xpath('//a[last()]').extract()
```

You could also qualify it with class

```
response.selector.xpath('//a[@class='wx4']').extract()
```

And if there could be more than one with that class, snag the last:

```
response.selector.xpath('//a[@class='wx4'][last()]').extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//a[@class='wx4' and text()='next']
```

This will search for a link that's styled with class "wx4" and its text is "next".

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check the web page to find out whether it has to be splashed at first:

```
scrapy shell your_url
response.body
```

Check if it's consistent with the source code you get from the browser. If not, use scrapinghub/splash. Firstly download and configure docker, and then execute:

```
pip install scrapy_splash
sudo docker pull scrapinghub/splash
sudo docker run -p 8050:8050 -p 8051:8051 scrapinghub/splash
```

in your terminal.

Then use `scrapy shell` in new terminal.

Then write lua_script for splash to execute the js to go to the bottom of the page like:

```
lua_script = '''
function main(splash)
    splash:go(splash.args.url)
    splash:wait(2)
    splash:runjs("your_javascript")
    splash:wait(2)
    return splash:html()
end
'''
```

And:

```
import json
import requests
splash_url = 'http://localhost:8050/execute'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
data = json.dumps({'lua_source': lua_script})
response = requests.post(splash_url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Then check:

```
response.content
```

to see if it's consistent.